# Are dashboards important or should users be directed to an information page?

Tags: user-behavior, interface, information-architecture, user-centered-design

I'm designing a platform where users manage multiple marketing campaigns. So there is a main page with the list of campaigns with minimal details (campaign name, active dates, etc). When you select a campaign, it would then go to another page revealing more details.

I wasn't sure if it was good practice to give them a dashboard/welcome page for each campaign (which includes a little bit more campaign details with a read more button that goes to a full details page and some analytics underneath),  or if I should send users directly to a page with full campaign details with the analytics on a separate page.

There were pros and cons to both as listed below:

**Dashboard**

Pros: eases user into campaign, have overview

Cons: user might overlook information, information might be redundant

**Separate Details/Analytics**

Pros: Information all in one place, looks cleaner/more differentiated between purpose of pages

Cons: Cognitive overload, overwhelming for user

**Diagram of platform structure**

[image: Campaign Structure Options]

I would love to hear other's advice on best UX practices with this, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose the separate screens option, but make the landing page be the analytics page.

1. The time till the user reaches their useful analytics details for their campaign is still one click away from the list.
2. The screens are cleanly organised and vertical space is saved not trying to do everything on the same page with a dashboard.
3. The details of a campaign sounds less valuable than the active analytics and may only be checked occasionally if something is forgotten.

Comment: 4 - in the mockup, the analytics are already given 2x ~ 3x the space that the description is, so it's already prioritized.

Comment: Another point i missed for the dashboard view, you may need to scroll down to reach all of the analytics details. This may compromise navigation to the campaign details screen because you need to vertically scroll all the way back up again to press it.